# Qt intercepting undo / redo of widgets

Tags: c++, qt

I have an application with several QPlainTextEdits, which may also be added or removed dynamically. I am keeping track of a global QUndoStack. Whenever a QPlainTextEdit is focused and the user presses CTRL + Z or CTRL + SHIFT + Z, I intercept this using

```
void TextEdit::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event) {

   if ((QApplication::keyboardModifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier) && event->key() == Qt::Key_Z) {
        if (QApplication::keyboardModifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier) {
            m_commandEditBox->commandScrollArea()->centralWidget()->redo();
        } else {
            m_commandEditBox->commandScrollArea()->centralWidget()->undo();
        }
        return;
    }
....
```

In the if-else statement you can see that instead of performing the undo/redo of the QPLainTextEdit I am instead calling the `CentralWidget::undo/CentralWidget::redo` functions. I have implemented simple classes that inherit from `QUndoCommand` that store a pointer to the `QPlainTextEdit` that I can then  use from the centralWidget to actually undo things done to the QPlainTextEdit when these undo/redo commands are at the top of the stack by calling `QPlainTextEdit::undo()`.

This solution seems rather brittle however, as maybe some users will actually expect CTRL + Y for redo etc., and on macs I will need to use the ⌘ button. Is there some better way in which I can intercept only undo redo events from the widget? I would like to do something like query the `QKeyEvent` in a platform independent manner.

P.S. I was contemplating a different solution, namely overriding the undo and redo function of `QPlainTextEdit` so that they call the centralWidget undo/redo functions, but the undo/redo of `QPlainTextEdit` are not virtual...

Comment: You are describing how did you implemented something (and you did that in wrong way) and I do not see description what functionality you needed to achieve. AFAIK undo redo should work out of the box (just set properties of QTextEdit/QTextDocument no interaction with events is needed). Please explain what kind of functionality you are trying to deliver to end user.

Comment: The functionality I am trying to deliver is this: When a QPlainTextEdit is focused and the user presses the key combination for an undo or redo, that undo redo should not be executed but instead some custom code written by me should be executed.

Comment: I think that this is a weird behavior. The user can do a lot of things before pressing the undo combination. By then, the undo stack has no info of what the user has done.

Comment: Simply [disable `redo` `undo` functionality](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#undoRedoEnabled-prop) of text document and then use key sequence to do custom action.

Comment: @MarekR Thanks for your comment. This was my initial approach. However, after some tinkering I realized that it was quite hard to implement this in a way that is intuitive. For instance typing a letter behaves differently to typing an enter (in this case a new undo event is created) which is again different from a back space etc. So instead of doing all this myself and probably not doing it as well the Qt folks have done it, I decided on this approach.

Comment: @MarekR As per your first comment, you eluded to something I did in a wrong way. This is likely true but I am not sure what you are referring to. Maybe it is already clear now, otherwise feel free to elaborate if you want :)

Comment: You shouldn't change how keyboard is handled just to change behavior of `QTextDocument`, this is buggy approach. Note that they might be different ways to invoke `undo`/`redo` then just key sequence.

Comment: So I have been coming back to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same remarks as before, this is a weird behavior to me. The user can do a lot of things before pressing the undo combination. By then, the undo stack has no info of what the user has done. For the cross platform problem, `QKeySequence` can be used.

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QUndoStack>
#include <QPlainTextEdit>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event) override;

private:
    QPlainTextEdit edit_;
    QUndoStack undo_stack_;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    edit_.installEventFilter(this);
    this->setCentralWidget(&edit_);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    if (watched != &edit_ || event->type() != QEvent::KeyPress)
        return false;

    QKeyEvent *key_event = dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
    QKeySequence key_sequence{static_cast<int>(key_event->modifiers()) + key_event->key()};

    if (key_sequence == QKeySequence::Undo)
    {
        undo_stack_.undo(); // nothing in the stack
        qDebug() << "undo";
        return true;
    }
    else if (key_sequence == QKeySequence::Redo)
    {
        undo_stack_.redo(); // nothing in the stack
        qDebug() << "redo";
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ah Thanks this is exactly what I needed. I see why the behavior seems strange. All user interactions get stored in the global undo stack. So whenever the presses undo, the actions all get undone in the order in which they were performed. In this way the user can go back to the exact global state that the application occupied before. Thanks again for the answer :)